# In Magento, how do I change an API attribute to show on the base API products call, rather than for a single resource only?

Tags: php, api, rest, magento

In the Magento admin, when you are selecting which API attributes appear in the API call for products (System -> Web Services -> REST Attributes), some attributes have an asterisk by them. The asterisk means that those attributes are only returned when you request a single product (something like `/api/rest/products/2262`, instead of `/api/rest/products`).

I need one of those attributes to be shown in the multi-product request. This will save hundreds of API calls. So how do I change an attribute (for example Product URL) to no longer be "returned for a single resources only", but instead show up when I hit the base call? (`/api/rest/products`)